# Powershell replace in text

Tags: powershell

Can anyone help tell me
I have text, I need to delete everything in it, after certain characters and before certain characters
text like this:

//test/gga/ext/scs/result?+index=4&+index=3&+rel=%22prev%22&+rel=%22prev%22&p=2

I need a delete all after 'result?' and before 'p=' using Powershell

And after this text will be //test/gga/ext/scs/result?p=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic approach would be to use split("?") to seperate the URL at the ? Then you take the second part and plot it at & and take the last item.

```
$parts = $url.split("?")
$parts_two = parts[1].split("&")
```

And then just build the new url

```
$new_url = "{parts[0]}?{$parts_two[-1]}"
```

There might be some typo but this could be a simple approach

Comment: Sorry forgot the code part but I used a tablet, and it's not an url it's an unc path but I guess we get the jist :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you.

```
$url = "//test/gga/ext/scs/result?+index=4&+index=3&+rel=%22prev%22&+rel=%22prev%22&p=2"
$newUrl = $url.Substring(0,26)+"p=2"

$newUrl
```